# Sistema de login e senha sem banco de dados não está permitindo acesso

Tags: php, login

Quando o *script* abaixo é testado não dá um retorno de que o *login* ou senha estão inválidos. Entretanto pelo que entendo o código está certo. O que será que está acontecendo?

```
<?php
    session_start();    

    //O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
    if((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
        //$senha = md5($senha);


        if (($senha == "123")  &&  ($usuario == "joaoborba@gmail.com" )){
        header("Location: administrativo.php");

        }else{  
            //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    //O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
    }else{
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Não da retorno significa o que? deveria escrever uma mensagem na tela(via sessão no index.php)?

Comment: Se está "sem banco de dados" (no titulo da pergunta!) você precisa remover o `mysqli_real_escape_string`, assim `$senha = $_POST['senha']` e `$usuario = $_POST['email']`. O `mysqli_real_escape_string` exige conexão com o banco de dados, se não possui não será possível usa-lo.